Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module '.../@intlify_core-base.js?v=dd61e0ad' doesn't provide an export named: 'CORE_ERROR_CODE...' vue-i18n.mjs
I'm currently migrating a Vue 3 compositional API app to Nuxt 3 and I get one error that I cannot figure out and it seems to be related to the i18n plugin.
I get following error in the browser console:
Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module 'http://localhost:3001/_nuxt/node_modules/.cache/vite/client/deps/@intlify_core-base.js?v=dd61e0ad' doesn't provide an export named: 'CORE_ERROR_CODES_EXTEND_POINT' vue-i18n.mjs:7:40

The line in the script is:
import { CORE_WARN_CODES_EXTEND_POINT, CORE_ERROR_CODES_EXTEND_POINT, createCompileError, DEFAULT_LOCALE, updateFallbackLocale, setFallbackContext, createCoreContext, clearDateTimeFormat, clearNumberFormat, setAdditionalMeta, getFallbackContext, NOT_REOSLVED, isTranslateFallbackWarn, isTranslateMissingWarn, parseTranslateArgs, translate, MISSING_RESOLVE_VALUE, parseDateTimeArgs, datetime, parseNumberArgs, number, isMessageAST, isMessageFunction, fallbackWithLocaleChain, NUMBER_FORMAT_OPTIONS_KEYS, DATETIME_FORMAT_OPTIONS_KEYS, registerMessageCompiler, compile, registerMessageResolver, resolveValue, registerLocaleFallbacker, setDevToolsHook } from "/_nuxt/node_modules/.cache/vite/client/deps/@intlify_core-base.js?v=dd61e0ad";

The app does not continue at this point and crashes with this error.
Although the error comes from vue-i18n.mjs the translation strings are shown correctly on the page, until it crashes.
Has anyone an idea what is wrong here?

The solution was that I needed to uninstall vue-i18n npm packages, although I was not importing it, disabled auto import and was using @nuxtjs/i18n, it still will somehow end up in your bundle.
So just: npm uninstall vue-i18n will solve the problem.
